# Comment belongs_to one of several models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

My scenario is that there are several different models which can have comments. Trying to figure out the relationships:

```
Post
  has_many :comments

Update
  has_many :comments

Comment
  belongs_to EITHER :post OR :update (but not both)????
```

Whats the proper way to set up the comment relationships? I want to be able to call `Post.comments` and `Update.comments`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smells like a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations):

> With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association. For example, you might have a picture model that belongs to either an employee model or a product model.

So you'd want something like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Update < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

You'd have to set up a few things in the database for this to work as well. See the [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) section of the [Active Record Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for details on the columns you'll need.

Comment: +1 as usual :-)  thank you for the link to the Feynman series btw!

Comment: @Tilo: Thanks, RPF is one my heros, the [Sagan Series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oY59wZdCDo0) is worth some time too.

Comment: spot on - exactly what it looks like polymorphic was created for

Comment: how about `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` - should I just set them with a hidden field in the view or is there a better way

Comment: @brittohalloran: You could or use the `post.create_comment` or `post.build_comment` approach.